# Specify the require-attribute for two submit-buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, attributes, submit

I have two submit-buttons:

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save">save</button>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="delete">delete</button>
  
  <input name="text" placeholder="Text here" required/>
</form>
```

I want to use the required-attribute for the save-button, but not for the delete-button.

How can I do this?

Comment: add an onclick listener to delete btn and use preventDefault()?

Comment: But preventDefault() will stop the submit, but I want to use the delete-submit-button to delete something.

Comment: ok maybe remove all required attribute when you click delete btn?

Comment: Already tryed with the .submit()-function (jquery). But there is the problem, that it runs after the require-check. :(

Comment: i tried adding onclick listener to delete btn to add novalidate to form element like so document.querySelector("#form").setAttribute("novalidate", true), worked for me

Comment: Thank you very much :) that works perfectly!

Comment: np, glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `novalidate` attribute to your form when you click on delete btn with an onclick listener to skip form validation.

```js
function skipValidate() {
  document.querySelector("#form").setAttribute("novalidate", true)
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save">save</button>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="delete" onclick="skipValidate()">delete</button>
  
  <input name="text" placeholder="Text here" required/>
</form>
```